# how to accumulate the value of position() function in xslt

Tags: xslt, netcdf, ncml

I have this xml file

```
<netcdf xmlns="http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/netcdf/ncml-2.2" location="file:/dev/null" iosp="lasp.tss.iosp.ValueGeneratorIOSP" start="0" increment="1">
    <attribute name="title" value="Vector time series"/>
    <dimension name="time" length="100"/>
    <variable name="time" shape="time" type="double">
        <attribute name="units" type="String" value="seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00"/>
    </variable>
    <group name="Vector" tsdsType="Structure" shape="time">
        <variable name="x" shape="time" type="double"/>
        <variable name="y" shape="time" type="double"/>
        <variable name="z" shape="time" type="double"/>
    </group>
</netcdf>
```

and I need the xslt file which gives the output like this

```
1.time
2.Vector
```

which are the name attribute of two tags: variable and group. Currently I have the code like this

```
 <xsl:for-each select="document($path)//*[local-name()='variable']">
        <xsl:if test="string-length( @*[local-name()='name'] ) >1">
        <li>
         <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@*[local-name()='name']"/>
        </li>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:for-each select="document($path)//*[local-name()='group']">
        <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@*[local-name()='name']"/>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

and it will give me

```
1.time
1.Vector
```

So how can I reach my goal by this position() function or there are any other better way to do this in XSLT? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position()` but it should be used inside the same repetition instruction. Declare the namespace with prefix say `x` and use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document($path)//x:netcdf/*
      [self::x:variable or self::x:group]"/>
```

Moreover I would use `xsl:number` like:

```
<xsl:number value="position()" format="1."/>
```

Consider also to declare the default namespace in your stylesheet so that you can get rid of `local-name()` tests.

Comment: I tried to do this <xsl:for-each select="document($path)//*[local-name()='variable' or local-name='group']"/> but this syntax doesn't work. do you know what's the syntax to chose two nodes at one select statement? Thanks for the reply

Comment: sorry for the miscode, I forgot the parenthesis in the expression. See my edited answer and check it now.